# The possibility of ESD in an isolated, mobile system

Tags: esd

When you have an isolated, battery powered device, then shouldn't you expect ESD?

Let's say I have two boards connected with each other through cables and connectors. The components on the PCBs are powered by batteries, and all of these are installed in a plastic enclosure. So this is a system with floating ground.

I heard that self-discharge does not occur in an isolated system. But is it really the case? When the device is transported and mounted somewhere,    all metals and insulators must have been charged up. Some of those should have different polarity. Then shouldn't you expect, theoretically and practically, ESD through air, or through a thin material at some point?

What if the device is moved frequently? In that case cables, connectors don't have stable contact. So charges can move from one to another suddenly. Don't you have to expect ESD through sudden contact between the cables, enclosure, the boards, and so on?

Answer (score 2):

I know of an example where ESD was an issue on a battery powered device.

I used to work at a company where they once had an issue with failing hospital pagers. These pagers are the small battery powered devices carried around by doctors so they can be reached anywhere in the hospital. These pagers had charging contacts at the bottom so that they could be charged at night in a special stand.

The failure related to these battery contacts. It appeared that in a certain hospital there was an elevator which had a (metal) buttons. Sometimes these buttons somehow collected a charge so if you'd press them with your finger you would receive a small shock.

So what did the doctors do? They used the bottom of their pager to press the button! Then sometimes the button would discharge through the charging contacts damaging the electronics.

Fortunately it was quite easy to fix this (in newer designs) by adding some ESD protection at the battery charging contacts.

So, being battery powered does not mean that a device is immune to ESD. An ESD event can still happen through external contacts or at any other point in the design where electrical isolation is not good enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the real-world example. But I wanted to know if ESD occurs in a really, or effectively well, isolated system.

Comment: Probably it will not. But you might think it is an isolated system, when I probe it with my 20 kV ESD tester, I might still find weak spots. But assuming there are no weak spots then sure, ESD should not occur.

Comment: By the weak spots do you mean spots inside the enclosure or spots on the enclosure?

Comment: Parts of the enclosure that aren't properly protecting against for example 5 kV. You might have a switch which is partly metal so conductive, that might also be a weak spot. I suggest you read up on ESD as understanding it makes things easier. Now you might see problems where there aren't any and not see real issues.